# $destroy event not being called on navigation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have registered for hardware back button event `registerBackButtonAction` inside my controller and using `$destroy` event to unregister the event. But the event is not getting called when I navigate to different page (state). What am I missing?

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $location, $rootScope, $http) {
  // Register hardware back button
  var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
    return;
  }, 100);

  console.log('scope on');
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    console.log('destroy called');
    deregister();
  })
})
```

In console I dont see `destroy called`. Please help me fix this.

**Update:**
In the browser when I navigate from Home to Login the elements of Home still exist in the browser. I guess that is the reason why destroy is not getting called. So the question is should I fire the event manually or should be Home page be actually destroyed when I move to Login?

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- Push notification -->
    <script src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
    <!-- Geo location -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <!-- app js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page are loaded as part of state via template in app.js:

```
  .state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML. Maybe with the navigation $scope is not destroyed as the element the scope belongs to is not removed.

Comment: This looks perfectly right, however there are is a case you have to trigger the destoy event yourself, and that is if you have a directive with a controller within a transcluded element. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help guys. In my framework the elements of first loaded page are not removed hence `$destroy` is not called. The workaround is to use the event `$ionicView.leave` to deregister, so instead of

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', deregister);
```

use:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', deregister);
```

Complete code:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $location, $rootScope, $http) {
  // Register hardware back button
  var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event)         {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
    return;
  }, 100);

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', deregister);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to wrap deregister() in an anonymous function. Then it worked for me.

```
var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
    $state.go('app.start');
}, 100);

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () {
    deregister();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Work for me

```
var deregister = null;

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
        function () {
                navigator.Backbutton.goHome(function() { 
                  console.log('hidden');
                }, function() {
                  navigator.app.exitaApp();
                });
        }, 100
    );     
})
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () {
    deregister();
});
```